# How to align text using shiny html?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny, popover

In the code at the bottom, I successfully justify-align the bullet-point text in the popover when hovering over the information circle. However, I still can't figure out how to justify-align its header immediately above as shown in this image. If I remove the `ul` from the line `tags$style('.popover ul {padding: 15px; text-align: justify;}')`, everthing is justified but I lose all other desired formatting. How would I modify this code so I can cleanly justify that header paragraph too?

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style('.popover ul {padding: 15px; text-align: justify;}'),
  br(),
  uiOutput("uiExample")
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uiExample <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tags$span("Little circle >>"),
      tags$span(
        popify(
          icon("info-circle", verify_fa = FALSE),
          "Placeholder",
          paste(
           "Here is an excerpt from a famous poem Still I Rise:",
           "<ul>",
             "<li>You may write me down in history With your bitter, twisted lies,</li>",
             "<li>You may tread me in the very dirt. But still, like dust, I will rise.",
             "Does my sassiness upset you...</li>",
           "</ul>"
           )
        )
      )  
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your CSS:

```r
'.popover-content {text-align: justify;}'
```

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style('.popover ul {padding: 15px; text-align: justify;}',
             '.popover-content {text-align: justify;}'),
  br(),
  uiOutput("uiExample")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$uiExample <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      tags$span("Little circle >>"),
      tags$span(
        popify(
          icon("info-circle", verify_fa = FALSE),
          "Placeholder",
          paste(
            "Here is an excerpt from a famous poem Still I Rise:",
            "<ul>",
            "<li>You may write me down in history With your bitter, twisted lies,</li>",
            "<li>You may tread me in the very dirt. But still, like dust, I will rise.",
            "Does my sassiness upset you...</li>",
            "</ul>"
          )
        )
      )  
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```